Como utilizo el consult en swi-Prolog
Hola quisiera saber como usar en consult() en swi-Prolog en windows lo estoy escribiendo asi consult('C:\Users\monge\OneDrive\Documentos\Programacion\Prolog.pl'). y no me sirve de hecho me manda un error.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
